# Better way to get a all-in-one view of Inspec reports

Tags: chef-infra, inspec

We are currently using Inspec 4.18.85. In order to run parallel tests on multiple servers, we club jenkins pipeline with ansible. And this results in reports being generated in multiple servers.

We tried deploying inspec_exporter to get overall metrics on tests run vs pass/failures and that works.But the image has got vulnerabilities . Another way would be to get all the HTML reports from all servers to one server and expose them as urls using a proxy.

I wanted to check if there are any other tools out there which can give a all-in-one view of Inspec reports from multiple servers?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the  output is json file:

```html
 reporter:
       - html:report/%{platform}_%{suite}_report.html
       - json:report/%{platform}_%{suite}_report.json
```

After kitchen test, **you parse all json file, generate to a file html.**
I use python lib panda to generate a html.